# LINQ to Objects filtering

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class, BillingProvider, which contains a list of Claims.  Separately, I have a list of the claim numbers which contain errors.  I want to exclude the claims with errors and, if all the claims under any BillingProvider have errors, then exclude the BillingProvider too.  I've created a simplified mock-up of the situation.  The LINQ query below excludes the errors but returns the BillingProvider multiple times.

```
class Program
{
    class BillingProvider
    {
        internal string TaxId { get; set; }
        internal List<Claim> Claims = new List<Claim>();
    }

    class Claim
    {
        internal int ClaimNumber { get; set; }
        internal string ClaimDescr { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var allBillingProviders = new List<BillingProvider>
        {
            new BillingProvider
            {
                TaxId = "123456789",
                Claims =  new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim {ClaimNumber = 1, ClaimDescr = "First Claim"},
                    new Claim {ClaimNumber = 2, ClaimDescr = "Second Claim"},
                    new Claim {ClaimNumber = 3, ClaimDescr = "Third Claim"}
                }
            },

            new BillingProvider
            {
                TaxId = "012345678",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {

                    new Claim{ClaimNumber = 4, ClaimDescr = "Fourth Claim"},
                    new Claim{ClaimNumber = 5, ClaimDescr = "Fifth Claim"},
                    new Claim{ClaimNumber = 6, ClaimDescr = "Sixth Claim"},
                    new Claim{ClaimNumber = 7, ClaimDescr = "Seventh Claim"},
                    new Claim{ClaimNumber = 8, ClaimDescr = "Eighth Claim"}
                }
            }
        };


        // Set up errors
        var errors = new List<int> {2, 5};  // Claims 2 and 5 have erros and should be excluded


        var bpClaims = (from b in allBillingProviders
                        from c in b.Claims
                        where (!errors.Contains(c.ClaimNumber))
                        select b).ToList();

        foreach (var bpc in bpClaims)
            Console.WriteLine("Count of claims in {0} is {1}", bpc.TaxId, bpc.Claims.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

}

Comment: What count do you want to return for "123456789".. 3 or 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this in two steps:

```
var bpClaims = 
    allBillingProviders.Select(x => new BillingProvider()
      {
        TaxId = x.TaxId,
        Claims = x.Claims.Where(c => !errors.Contains(c.ClaimNumber)).ToList()
      })
    .Where(x => x.Claims.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  My BillingProvider class has a lot more fields than in the example, do I need to list ALL the fields again?

Comment: I would think about using [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) but if objects are many, and fields are many too, overhead of all those copying should be probably taken into consideration. Maybe get rid of LINQ and make simple `foreach` on providers, modyfing (removing) claims in place?

Comment: I've already done it - there were only about 12 more fields and I think overhead will be minimal.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

One way to use distinct, but since you may want to distinct by ClaimNumber since I think claim number will not be repeated you can use this library that has `DistictBy`

https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

```
var bpClaims = (from b in allBillingProviders
                        from c in b.Claims
                        where (!errors.Contains(c.ClaimNumber))
                        select b).DistinctBy(c=>c.ClaimNumber).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of the claim IDs without including the error claim IDs by doing this in your Console.WriteLine line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Count of claims in {0} is {1}", bpc.TaxId, bpc.Claims.Select(x=> x.ClaimNumber).ToList().Except(errors).Count());
```

Comment: Thanks, but my console test output is just that - test output.  I'm interested in the objects themselves!

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Glad you got a solution!